# Cucumber Junit5 Maven runtime options

Tags: maven, cucumber, command-line-arguments, junit5

I searched a lot and dont get it fixed. I want to start maven and execute a specific feature file.

I tried
**mvn test -Dcucumber.features**="src/cucumber/feature/Jenkins02_Regressiontest.feature"
, but that leads to an error:

[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase ".features=src/cucumber/feature/createStatements/COCA/COCA_Jenkins02_Regressiontest.feature". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format : or :[:]:. Available lifecycle phases are: pre-clean, clean, post-clean, validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classe
s, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, veri
fy, install, deploy, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]

With ":" there is no error, and maven builds but doesnt executes the feature file.
mvn test -Dcucumber:features="src/cucumber/feature/Jenkins02_Regressiontest.feature"

How can I run a specify featurefile ?
Has someone a documention or example to use the cucumber options as runtime parameters?

bye Jochen

Comment: It looks like you are doing command line calling wrong based on this message: `You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the forma`..

Comment: @khmarbaise sorry but your answer has been cut after forma.. As far as I understood your answer, i need to prepare a separate goal for every test?
So instead of "mvn test" i would call  "mv testA", "mvn testB", "mvn testC"?

Answer (score 0):

#1: inside my intelliJ it worked. Figure out which maven your intellij uses, and use the same

#2: adding other goals (clean, install) might help too

This works:
SET FEATURENAME=src/cucumber/feature/createStatements/AMA/AMA_create_statement.feature

CALL C:\maven\apache-maven-3.9.2\bin\mvn clean install test -Dcucumber.features="%FEATURENAME%"